# Angular2: User Service reset

Tags: angular, authentication

at first, sorry for my bad language. Im a student from germany.

I have implemented a user service in Angular. 2 Unfortunately the login works only partially. When a user passes the login screen and manually invoke a link in the address bar e. g. URL/chat, the user service will reset. The user has no more rights and is not logged in.

How can i improve my service?

Thanks for your answers :)

Login Component

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'login-form',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['login.component.scss']
    })
    export class LoginComponent {
    error:string;
    model = new User("", "");

    constructor(private userService: UserService,
                private router: Router,
                private ErrorHandler:ErrorHandlingService) {
    }
    onSubmit() {
        this.userService.login(this.model.email, this.model.password).subscribe(
            (result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
                }
            },
            (error) => {
              error = this.ErrorHandler.convertMessage(error);
              this.error = this.ErrorHandler.getUserError(error);
            }
            );
    }
    }
```

User Service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import {MiaIP} from './miacontroller.service';

    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {
    private loggedIn = false;
    private user ={
    "event": "",
    "data": {
    "firstname": "",
    "lastname": "",
    "token": "",
    "privileges": []
    }
    };

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.loggedIn = !!sessionStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    }
    login(email, password) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return this.http
            .post(MiaIP.MIA_ENDPOINT, JSON.stringify({ email, password }), {   headers: headers })
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map((res) => {
                if (!!res.event) {
                  sessionStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.data.token);
                  this.loggedIn = true;
                  this.user.data.privileges = res.data.privileges;
                  this.user.event = res.event;
                  this.user.data.firstname =res.data.firstname;
                  this.user.data.lastname =res.data.lastname;
                  this.user.data.token = res.data.token;
                  console.log('chat ist: ',    this.user.data.privileges.indexOf('get_dashboard') >=1);
                }
                return !!res.event;
            }
            );
    }

    logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
    this.loggedIn = false;
    }
    isLoggedIn() {
        return this.loggedIn;
    }

    getUser(){
      return this.user;
    }

    getUsers(){
      return !!(this.user.data.privileges.indexOf('get_users') >=1)
    }
     getDashboard(){
      return !!(this.user.data.privileges.indexOf('get_dashboard') >=1)
    }
      getExperiment(){
      return !!(this.user.data.privileges.indexOf('get_experiment') >=1)
    }
      getChat(){
      return !!(this.user.data.privileges.indexOf('get_chat') >=1)
    }
      getOverview(){
      return !!(this.user.data.privileges.indexOf('get_overview') >=1)
    }
      getMyProfile(){
      return !!(this.user.data.privileges.indexOf('get_myprofile') >=1)
    }
      getScheduling(){
      return !!(this.user.data.privileges.indexOf('get_scheduling') >=1)
    }
    }
```

Chat component

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
    selector: 'chat',
    templateUrl: 'chat.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['chat.component.scss']
    })
    export class ChatComponent{
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user hits enter on the address bar it will trigger a page reload, so it's normal that all the app will re-initialize.
(some exception may make if you use #has urls, but I will not go that way)

You probably want to store the login info in cookies or in localstorage. So it's not exactly related to Angular2.